# Combining the elements at a given index in a list of tuples with another list to form pairs

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists:

```
x = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
y = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I want to take every first item of each tuple in the first list and combine it with the second list to look like this:

```
output = [(1, 'A'), (4, 'B'), (7, 'C')]
```

Also in both list I'll have few thousands of elements, so I would appreciate solution that will be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
output = [(a[0], b) for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

you can also preprocess `x` with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions):

```
from operator import itemgetter
output = list(zip(map(itemgetter(0), x), y))
```

output:

```
[(1, 'A'), (4, 'B'), (7, 'C')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output = [(x[i][0],y[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
```

Comment: It is generally recommended in Python to use `zip` and avoid manipulating indices.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
y = ['A', 'B', 'C']

output = [ (i[0], j) for i, j in zip(x, y) ]

print(output)

[(1, 'A'), (4, 'B'), (7, 'C')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `zip()`:

```
list(zip(list(zip(*x))[0], y))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'A'), (4, 'B'), (7, 'C')]
```